# Decompressing PDF in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, qpdf

I have pdfs with compressed data that qpdf decompresses and saves as a decompressed readable pdf. But I would like to make a node javascript-only solution that I can package up so my users don't have to install qpdf. There are a lot of javascript npm libraries, but none of them seem to have the same simple "open with uncompress and save" functionality of qpdf. Is this do-able with javascript only?

Comment: So, you don't actually need to parse the PDF?  You just need basically a gzip library?

Comment: PDF parsing and manipulation is more traditionally associated with system-level programming, like C++ or Java. But you can try libraries like pdf-lib, That can be used for various PDF manipulations

Comment: You can do it with https://github.com/coherentgraphics/coherentpdf.js/ (disclaimer, which I wrote). Use `fromFile` (server) or `fromMemory` (client) then `decompress` then `toFile` (server) or `toMemory` (client).

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'coherentpdf' libarary, I was able to lose the qpdf dependency and do it all in js. (The pdf files I'm working with all use Flate for compression.)

This is basically the node.js code:

```
let coherentPDF = require('coherentpdf');

let pdf = coherentPDF.fromFile('compressed.pdf', '');
coherentPDF.decompress(pdf);
coherentPDF.toFile(pdf, 'decompressed.pdf', false, false);
```